# Serverless and Shared Handlers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In using the Serverless framework, is it possible to have shared handlers?

If you have multiple domains and there are some handlers that are shared across those domains, how would you reference them within the **servlerless.yml** file? We have common handlers where their functionality is different based on parameters passed in through the environment section of the **serverless.yml** file but cannot figure out how to reference them correctly through the **serverless.yml** file, more specifically, the **handler** entry.

I have tried entries such as:

```
retreiveFoo:
  handler: ../common/common_retreive.retreive
```

and the directory structure looks like this

```
common:
  common_retrieve.js

fooA:
  serverless.yml <- retrieveFoo defined here
  other_functions.js
```

However, this does not seem to work.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, you can't import code from outside of the root folder, which is where the serverless.yml